# What exactly are the rules for configuring postcss.config.js (mainly with tailwndcss)?

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css, vue-cli, postcss

The number of variants that exist to showcase how `postcss.config.js` has to be configured is extremely confusing. There are examples (like the one at the `tailwindcss` documentation) that use this:

```js
// Example 1:
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

then there are those which require the libraries:

```js
// Example 2:
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    require('tailwindcss'),
    require('postcss-preset-env')({
      stage: 0,
      'nesting-rules': true
    })
  },
}
```

Others require external libs before they configure `module.exports`:

```js
// Example 3:

const tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');
const postcssPresetEnv = require('postcss-preset-env');


module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss,
    postcssPresetEnv
  },
}
```

and again some more that are necessary, when a configuration file that is not named according to the defaults has to be incorporated.

Today I get this error, when running `yarn dev` with a postcss.config.js as show in Example 2:

```sh
Syntax Error: /[path]/_pod-test/postcss.config.js:3
    require('tailwindcss'),
             ^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected string
```

When I remove the line with "tailwindcss", the same thing happens for "postcss-preset-env":

```sh
Syntax Error: /Volumes/_III_/Z_WWW/_ZZZ PoD/_pod-test/postcss.config.js:3
    require('postcss-preset-env')({
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected string
```

When I then switch to a setup as shown in example 1, I get this error:

```sh
Syntax Error: Error: PostCSS plugin tailwindcss requires PostCSS 8.
Migration guide for end-users:
https://github.com/postcss/postcss/wiki/PostCSS-8-for-end-users
```

I do use postcss 8.3.9!

This all happens in a project that was setup with `vue-cli` as a Vue2 project.

Which witch craft do I have to apply to make this setup work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a subtle, but very important difference between examples 1 and 2 that I posted.

**Example 2 is actually wrong!**

While example 1 uses **objects** to configure the parameters of the plugins, the 2nd example uses function calls. And those must be put in an **ARRAY** (meaning: brackets instead of curly braces).

This would be correct version of Example 2:

```js
// Example 2 fixed:

module.exports = {
  plugins: [  // <= here we MUST use brackets!
    ... [function calls] ...
  ],
}
```

I have not yet tested if that is also true for example 3 (but I assume so).

Hope this helps somebody!

Comment: Can some one atleast point to official postcss docs where it explains how to configure postcssconfig and explains both syntax

Answer (score 1):

In `package.json` I have:

```json
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": [
      "postcss-import",
      "tailwindcss",
      "postcss-preset-env",
      "autoprefixer",
      "cssnano"
    ]
  }
```

*That's my full setup for production. I have tailwind `3.0.23`, but it probably works with any version anyway.*

If you use `cssnano`, you don't need to set the `tailwindcss/nesting` for `postcss-preset-env` which tailwind recommends in their docs: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#nesting

Why? because `cssnano` merges the repeated code that they both produces. This workaround with `cssnano` is recommended by one of the tailwind team member: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/4634#issuecomment-861392246

Comment: Thank you, Lucas! Meanwhile - since we have a new tailwind version - it would be of great help, if you could mention whether your config is valid for tailwind v2 and / or v3 (only).

Comment: I have version `3.0.23` of tailwind, but I think it's compatible with any version because this config is more related to postcss than tailwind.

Answer (score 0):

In your terminal run the below command to install tailwind css and its dependencies via npm.

```
npm install tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
```

It is possible to get the error message that you mentioned when you try to run the project

```
Error: PostCSS plugin tailwindcss requires PostCSS 8.
```

Run the following code to uninstall previous installation and fix the error

```
npm uninstall tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer 
npm install tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat postcss@^7 autoprefixer@^9
```

Next, you need to generate both Tailwind and PostCSS config files

```
npx tailwindcss init -p
```

Your config files should look like this

**postcss.config file**

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
};
```

**tailwindcss.config file**

```
module.exports = {
  future: {
    // removeDeprecatedGapUtilities: true,
    // purgeLayersByDefault: true,
  },
  purge: [],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {},
  plugins: [],
};
```

Finally, open up your main.js file and import the tailwind.css file containing the tailwind directives i.e

```
import './css/tailwind.css'
```

Comment: Thank you, I know about the downgrade path (should have mentioned it). The culprit is the postcss-preset-env. There is no one standard that seems to work, neither with react, nor vue (also not with vue & vite). postcss is pretty broken ATM.

Answer (score 0):

**for me is THIS config that can run correctly :**

```
// Example 3:

const tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');
const postcssPresetEnv = require('postcss-preset-env');


module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss,
    postcssPresetEnv
  },
}
```

**and with this versions libraries :**

```
"postcss": "^8.4.6",
"postcss-cli": "^9.1.0",
"tailwindcss": "^3.0.18",
```

I do not try all features postcss at this time but basic process file into CLI run correctly...